# Get index to start at [1] instead of [0] in array with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have the following code:-

```
var $div = $("#preloader");
$.each($.imgNames, function (i, val) {
    $("<img />").attr("src", $.largePath + val).addClass('PRELOADED').appendTo($div);
});
```

Is it possible to get jQuery to start the index from [1] instead of the [0]?

Comment: it's there a particular reason for that?

Comment: Hi Jorge, the array starts at [1] as it's used to setup navigation dynamically, so the first string in the array is not used.

Comment: $.imgNames is a global variable on the site (the array in question to be indexed from [1])

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$.each($.imgNames, function (i, val) {
    if(i === 0) return true; //in jQuery equivalent to "continue" statement in javascript for-loops 
    // ... rest of your code
```

Comment: Thanks antyrat. Works a charm.

Answer (score 2):

Just check whether current index is zero, and if it is don't do anything:

```
if (i == 0) {
    return;
}

$("<img ...")...
```